# How to fix position of central content when vertical scroll is visible?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to fix position of center content when vertical scroll is visible due to large amount of data. It slightly moved as shown in bellow pictures:

Without vertical scroll is fine
[image]

now with vertical scroll:

[image]

how i can fix central div when scroll visible?

Comment: Its still centered! The content moves a bit because the viewport now displays the scrollbar, which is probably 20px wide. THe only way around this is to use jQuery and add a 'Mac style' scrollbar to your site. However, I wouldn't recommend it because there are still lots of users that simply expect the 'traditional scrollbar' so its not really user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to always show a scrollbar whether it's required on not.

Just add `overflow:scroll-y` to the body element.